# How to pass Windows Authentication credential using $.Ajax to Web API service

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

apologies if the question is dumb, to be honest I myself feel I'm missing something very simple...!

here's the case:
we have a web site (A) which uses windows authentication
the application calls another web api site (B) hosted on the same server which also uses windows authentication.

with following codes I'm able to call web apis and impersonate the user:

```
var wi = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
wi.Impersonate();
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
    //call the api ... successfully impersonated!
}
```

With above I can call web apis on site B from site A (in the server side code).

My problem is on the client side (javascript) that I need to call ajax methods to GET/POST/... web apis.
I know I need to add xhrFields to ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (res) {
    },
    error: function (res) {
    }
});
```

However this prompts for credentials, while user already has provided credentials to browse the website A.
Any ways to somehow include the credentials (or token) from the session into the ajax call?

thanks in advance,

Comment: so to clarify: calling `API B` from `backend A` is fine, but calling `API B` directly from `frontend A` is an issue?

Comment: @timur Yes, impersonation in backend A let's me call API B methods.
but XHRFields 'withCredentionals' still prompts a secondary authentication window.

Answer (score 0):

Web Api site (B) must attach header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Line 1:
It response if the request from origin server (PHP: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` OR Apache: `{HTTP_ORIGIN}`)

Line 2:
if the header response true, it will send the credential

Answer (score 0):

In addition to including the `withCredentials: true` option in the Ajax call, you must add a few settings in the REST API configuration. If you only enable Windows authentication for the REST API from IIS, you are likely to get the `401` error from the client, since browsers make an `OPTIONS` call before making the original call to validate `CORS` access.

[image: OPTIONS method call from Browser]

To enable this validation, you must also enable **Anonymous Authentication** in your REST API from IIS.

[image: Enable authentication from IIS]

And add this exception in the `web.config` file of the REST API:

```
<system.webServer>
.....
<security>
 <authorization>
    <add accessType="Allow" verbs="OPTIONS" users="?" />
    <add accessType="Deny" verbs="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE" users="?" />
 </authorization>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Where Anonymous Authentication is allowed for `OPTIONS` type requests, in order to allow `CORS` validation from the browser. And Anonymous Authentication is denied for the rest of the operations: `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`.

You must consider that the `OPTIONS` method will be enabled for all anonymous calls and you should not use it in your REST API if you are going to validate the authentication.